# SQL query incredibly slow when using simple NOT IN (SUBQUERY)

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

I've been trying to get an inverted result set from two tables, below are some technical details:

Initial Table

```
CREATE TABLE `initial_table` (`id` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

Another Table

```
CREATE TABLE `another_table` (`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`row_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',PRIMARY KEY (`id`),KEY `row_id` (`row_id`))
```

EXPLAIN of statement attempted

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1 | PRIMARY | initial_table | index | NULL | PRIMARY | 767 | NULL | 2965400 | Using where; | Using index
2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | another_table | index | NULL | row_id | 257 | NULL | 770452 | Using where; | Using index
```

Within another_table is a subset of initial_table. Initial table is roughly 3,000,000 rows, and another_table is 600,000 rows. I want to get the inverse of the results from another_table, essentially the 2,400,000 rows within initial_table that are not present in another_table.

I have tried the following queries:

```
INSERT INTO results_table SELECT a.id FROM initial_table AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN another_table AS z ON a.id = z.row_id WHERE z.row_id IS NULL
INSERT INTO results_table SELECT a.id FROM initial_table as a WHERE NOT IN (SELECT z.row_id FROM another_table AS z)
INSERT INTO results_table SELECT a.id FROM initial_table AS a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT z.row_id FROM another_table AS z WHERE a.id = z.row_id)
INSERT INTO results_table SELECT a.id FROM initial_table AS a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM another_table AS z WHERE a.id = z.row_id)
```

All of the above have yielded (at best) 34,000 rows in 4 hours of execution, with AWS stating it's selecting at about 1.89 SELECTs/second

Is there some form of optimization that I can perform here? Sadly the initial_table primary key is a varchar containing UUIDs rather than an integer based primary key, but at least all relevant columns are indexed. Not sure why it's so freaking slow since at least in theory, the WHERE NOT EXISTS (third) query should not be doing a table scan, just an index-based lookup :/

Comment: Just to clarify - the RDS instance this is running on is pretty decent - 4CPU/16GB RAM, it's not a hardware bottleneck - CPU maxes at about 30-40%.

Comment: That *is* a CPU bottleneck, of course, on a scale of 0 to 100...  with 4 vCPU, a single query can only consume 25%.  You also need to explain the discrepancy in key_len between the two tables (767/257) which implies two different collations of varchar(255) and no int(11) anywhere in sight.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - I wasn't aware that SQL was bound to one vCPU per query. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by discrepancy of the two key_lens, though I did have a mistake in my CREATE as row_id is supposed to be a varchar(255) not int(11).

I believe that it may be possible there is a bad/dummy key in the initial_table that is much longer than any retrieved and placed into another_table, would that explain the key_len difference?

Comment: 767 is the maximum number of bytes potentially required to store 255 utf8 characters -- (255 × 3) + 2 more to store the length (in the actual row)... so it is probably correct but not consistent with the other table, potentially requiring some kind of implicit conversion or cast.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
INSERT INTO results_table (id)
    SELECT a.id
    FROM initial_table a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM another_table z WHERE a.id = z.row_id);
```

For this query, you want an index on `another_table(row_id)`.

Comment: I didn't include in my initial post but I've already tried this - it had the same results. I've tested again using this query and I'm getting about 1.9 inserts/second, this has now been amended.

Comment: @TomPrentice . . . Do you have the index?

Comment: I do indeed have indexes set up - as shown in the CREATE statement I provided :)

Comment: @TomPrentice . . . Your table definitions do not match the columns used in the queries.

Comment: Sorry about that - that's been fixed too.